# ios avfoundation custom iso and duration

Tags: xcode, ios8, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to take a number of photos. I set my own ISO and duration with setExposureModeCustomWithDuration: . I have a slider to change these values based on the AVManualCam example from Apple. But the first time when i enter my app the camera doesn't use my setting, but it's own putting the ISO to the maximum value and the duration to a medium value. I use this code in the viewDidLoad method

```
    float newDuration=[self.durationValue.text floatValue];
    CMTime time=CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newDuration, 1000*1000*1000);
    [self.videoDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newDuration, 1000*1000*1000)  ISO:[self.isoValue.text intValue] completionHandler:nil];
```

and similiar code in the IBAction methods for the slinding values.
Can anyone please tell me how can i set some default values for the ISO and duration for the camera to use from the first time? After i set the values from the sliders the camera SOMETIMES uses those values. And this is another question: why only sometimes? has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: What is the initial isoValue.text and durationValue set to? Maybe try setting it within that app did load before calling it?